# How to call multiple stored procedures in a MySql database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server-2008

I am able to get this program to work with one stored procedure. Is it possible to call multiple stored procedures from MYSQL in C#? If so what is the most efficient way of doing so? Here is a snippet of my code to show what I've done thus far:

```
public static string RunSQL()
{
    // Here is where it is connecting to local host.
    string connStr = "server=localhost;user=xxxx;"
                     + "database=xxxx;port=3306;password=xxx;"
                     + "Allow User Variables=True";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

    // Here is where the connection gets opened.
    conn.Open();

    // Here I call the CN_renumber stored procedure.
    MySqlCommand CN_renumber = new MySqlCommand("CN_renumber", conn);
    CN_renumber.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    object result = CN_renumber.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Disconnect from local host.
    conn.Close();

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse your object of `MySQLCommand` multiple times, but before that you should make sure you call `myCommand.Parameters.Clear();`, then assign the new `Stored Procedure` name again.

Useful question with example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/670419/461564)

Comment: What I am looking to do now is to return a value in C# indicating that the stored procedure has completed.      

    I was thinking of doing something like this within the last MYSQL stored procedure to be called:
    
    int status =0   
    if (proc.result >0) then     {
    status = proc.result 
    }
    label.status