# Run one SqlCommand for two queries perfomance

Tags: c#

Till now i'm creating two sql command for running two different queries. I wondering if the performance will change if i will run the same sql command for execute this two queries

Here is my method till now

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
connection.Open();
using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandText1, connection))
{
}
using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandText2, connection))
{
}
// etc
}
```

Method 2

```
var command = new SqlCommand("<SQL Command>", myConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


command.CommandText = "<New SQL Command>";
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is there any difference in performance or it doesn't matter what i will use.

Comment: Obligatory link... [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Related issue: [Reusing SqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670407/reusing-sqlcommand). It's no matter which method you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance difference is negligible, but if you for ever and always want to run those exact two queries Method 2 saves opening a new connection to the Database. But you'll want to call `command.Parameters.Clear();` before setting the new `command.CommandText` property